# Directory Navigation with php and html

Tags: php, html, ftp, directory, smb

I am trying to create visual directory listing with php and html for a website. I want to be able to set a location/path where music/movies/pictures are stored whether it is on a server or on my local machine.

I want to show these items in a list and have the items have a onclick() function where it adds that folder name to the end of the path and shows all files in that directory, also have a back button that will take of the name of the last folder off the path and show the previous directory files.

So I want to have an upload to be able to upload the path to the music/movies.

I am basing this off of the program XMBC, which allows you to do this.

Not sure if this can be done within a website or not.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: This is definitely possible. Do you have any specific questions? As it stands, your question is not a very good fit for the format of StackOverflow.

Comment: Well what I am having trouble with is being able to set the path where my music/movies are stored and get an array of items or something back to work with. Especially on a server using smb preferably.